# clojure csv with escaped comma

Tags: parsing, csv, clojure

I am trying to parse a csv  string in clojure with escaped commas and no quote around fields like this one

```
"test1\,test2,test3"
```

I tried this libraries:

- [org.clojure/data.csv "0.1.2"]
- [cljcsv "1.3.1"]
- [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "2.0.0-alpha1"]

But none of them seems capable to recognize this correctly as `["test1,test2" "test3"]`
Does someone know a library which can do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've had good luck with [incanter](https://github.com/liebke/incanter). It may be overkill so you may want to just use OpenCSV (an incanter dependency.)

Comment: I'll add that I believe for it to be a valid CSV, you'd need the following: `"\"test1,test2\",test3"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an excellent excuse to write your own parser :-). 
You can use Instaparse: https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse

**Update:**
OK, I could not resist the temptation myself :-) 
**Update 2:** Allow escaped characters inside quoted strings.

```
(require '[instaparse.core :as insta])

(def custom-csv
  (insta/parser
    "file = (line <eol>)* line
     line = (field <','>)* field
     eol = '\\r'? '\\n'
     <field> = plain-field | quoted-field
     quoted-field = <'\\\"'> (#'[^\"\\\\]+' | escaped-char)* <'\\\"'>
     plain-field = (field-chars | escaped-char)*
     <field-chars> = #'[^\\\\\\r\\n,\\\"]+'
     escaped-char = #'\\\\.'
    "))

(def test-str 
"test1\\,test2,test3
te\\s\\\\t4,\"te,st
5\"")

(custom-csv test-str)
; Result:
; [:file
;  [:line
;   [:plain-field "test1" [:escaped-char "\\,"] "test2"]
;   [:plain-field "test3"]]
;  [:line
;   [:plain-field "te" [:escaped-char "\\s"] [:escaped-char "\\\\"] "t4"]
;   "te,st\n5"]]

(->> (custom-csv test-str)
     (insta/transform
       {
         :file list
         :line vector
         :plain-field str
         :quoted-field str
         :escaped-char second
       }))
; Result:
; (["test1,test2" "test3"] ["tes\\t4" "te,st\n5"])
```

Comment: Everyone should write their own parser at least once!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this library to me. I used it to write a parser similar to yours but with some simplifications. (No new lines in fields ....) Working quite well.

Answer (score 7):

You're not exactly parsing CSV data, but some derivation [of the convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) (note I didn't write "standard").

In CSV, commas are not escaped. That is something leaking into your data from C/C++/Java string escaping.  If it were typical CSV, it would be written like this

```
"a,b",c
```

Which clojure-csv supports.

```
user=> (csv/parse-csv (str "\"a,b\",c")) 
(["a,b" "c"])
```

You likely will have to write your own parser, or extend one of the aforementioned libraries, to handle this case.

Comment: Thanks. I like your comment that it's not standard .csv. It isn't.

Comment: I also have double quotes in my fields escaped with a backslash. How can i handle them?

Comment: Perhaps you should open a new question asking for pointers on implementing this problem. It's a bit larger scope than your original question.